# Should I use "the" or "a"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

In this sentence, should I use *the* or *a*?

> Mom: I think making a copy of this picture would be a good idea since your aunt wants a copy.
>   Me: Sure, I can make *the* copy.

Should I say "a copy" in order to make sense? Do I need to say "a copy" first and say "the copy" later in the conversation when referring to that copy? I'm not sure how early into the conversation I can start using *the* instead of *a*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either. Probably most speakers would tend to use the indefinite article ("**a** copy"). Not least because the preceding utterance used that form twice, and the definite article wouldn't really work for those earlier instances (it's plain invalid for the first, and awkward/highly unlikely for the second).

But there's nothing wrong with *"I can make **the** copy"*, because by then we're in a context where we know *which particular copy is being spoken of* (it's the one the aunt wants, and hopefully is going to get).